# Act upon an object calling a function?

Tags: c++

So say I was using this to create an object:

```
MyClass myObject;
```

and I had the function inside of the class to act upon the object. So one way could be using parameters, like this:

```
MyClass foo(MyClass a) {
return a;
}
```

Seems simple. But is there a way so I can use `myObject.foo()` and it would still return `a` even though I'm not using it as a parameter? One example could be some of the methods in `std::string` - you can use `std::string.swap()`, using the object for the `swap()` function.

Is there a way,  or am I being stupid?

Comment: Maybe not stupid, but certainly unclear.

Comment: Really, it is better to read some C++ book, rather then asking such questions here. C++ is a complicated language, and you cannot learn it by asking questions...

Comment: Clarified, by accepting an answer

Comment: @anxieux Yeah, I'm working my way through one now (part of the "In Easy Steps" series), and I haven't seen anything related to this yet, so thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that you original code of

```
MyClass foo(MyClass a) {
  return a;
}
```

does not actually return `a`.  It returns a *copy of `a`*, which itself is a copy of whatever instance of MyClass you passed into foo.  If you want to pass in a given object, act on it and return it, you need to use references, like so

```
MyClass & foo(MyClass & a) {
  return a;
}
```

This will ensure that the a you get back from a call to foo is the exact same object you passed into it.

Additionally, an object can always return a reference to itself in one of its members...

```
class MyClass { 
  MyClass & foo() { return *this; }
}
```

This is especially useful in classes where you might want to chain a large number of operations together...

```
MyClass my = MyClass().foo().bar("Hello").baz(5);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, this was the best explanation, resulting in the best answer for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside every member function is a magic secret parameter, which is a pointer to the object who's method was called, and the parameter's name is `this`.

```
MyClass& foo() { //returns reference to existing MyClass instead of making copies
    this->print(); //call a different member
    return *this;  //return a reference to itself. Common for `operator=` and such.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class's (non-`static`) member function, you can use `*this` to name the object the function was called on.

So:

```
MyClass MyClass::foo() {
    return *this;
}
```

(Notice that function returns a copy of the object.  If you don't want a copy, use a reference as in @Jherico's answer.)